# R - cannot use autoplot with dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, autoplot

I ran into this when trying to throw together some quick plots for exploratory analysis.  I wanted to use the `autoplot` function from `ggplot2` so that I wouldn't have to take the time to specify all the parameters and such.  Again, this is for exploratory analysis, not for generating plots to be shared/published.

For a quick, minimal example:

```
DF <- data.frame(major = c("Bio", "Chem", "Comp", "DataSci", "Maths", "STEM_other"),
                 count = c(38, 16, 19, 8, 15, 56))
```

... which, of course, results in the following dataframe:

```
> DF
       major count
1        Bio    38
2       Chem    16
3       Comp    19
4    DataSci     8
5      Maths    15
6 STEM_other    56
```

My hope was that `autoplot` would give me a simple bar chart or something, just enough for a quick look without too much trouble.  When trying to use the `autoplot` function, I get this error:

```
> autoplot(DF)
Error in `autoplot()`:
! Objects of class <data.frame> are not supported by autoplot.
ℹ have you loaded the required package?
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

It seems odd to me that dataframes would not be supported, when I would think many data sources would be organized in dataframes.  Is there something I am missing?

All of my searching pointed to issues with `autoplot` handling time-series data, which apparently can be corrected by also loading `ggfortify`.  This is not time-series data, so I would think loading `ggfortify` would not be any help in this case... I tried anyway to confirm, and I was correct (no change).

Is there some other package I need to install/load to make `autoplot` work?  Isn't the point to be able to make quick plots without spending too much time on them, or am I totally misusing `autoplot`?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: I suspect the answer is that dataframes are too flexible (compared to say an lm fit) to be able to make assumptions about what you want to plot from it. One function that might be useful for plotting dataframes is `GGally::ggpairs(DF)`.

Comment: I believe the "base case" (not base R) definition of `autoplot` is in `ggplot2`, where its documentation says: *"‘autoplot()’ uses ggplot2 to draw a particular plot **for an object of a particular class** in a single command. This defines the S3 generic that other classes and packages can extend"* (bold emphasis mine). The "base case" defined within `ggplot2` does nothing; if you look at `ggplot2:::autoplot.default` you'll see that it is not intended to do anything.

Comment: In a hasty search on my computer alone, I see `autoplot` methods for the following classes (reduced, not to over-drive my point): `bench::autoplot.bench_mark`, `fabletools::autoplot.fbl_ts`, `fabletools::autoplot.tbl_ts`, `fabletools::reexports`, `feasts::autoplot.tbl_cf`, `forecast::autoplot.acf`, `forecast::autoplot.decomposed.ts`, `forecast::autoplot.mforecast`, `zoo::autoplot.zoo`. The classes (`.bench_mark`, `fbl_ts`, etc) are assigned by specific functions in their respective packages.

Comment: Each package makes their `autoplot` method in a way that they believe highlights a takeaway(s) from the analysis or processing. Bottom line, `autoplot` is not a function that attempts to _guess_ what kind of plot you want, it is a "suggestion" by package authors for data from their functions.

Comment: Not your question, but when I'm looking how to make a particular plot, I often skim through https://r-graph-gallery.com: it's a picture-menu of sorts, where you can find a plot you like, then see the code and sample data they used to make that plot. I think you should be able to find what you're looking for within https://r-graph-gallery.com/barplot.html. Good luck!

Comment: I think I understand; I guess I misunderstood the functionality of `autoplot`.  

So, follow-up question: does there exist a function that does what I described above?  I can craft good-quality visuals all day using `ggplot`, but it would be nice to be able to make quick charts for exploratory purposes without as much effort.

Comment: Base graphics can create a simple chart `barplot(count ~ major, data=DF)`

Comment: The problem with "doing something quickly" is that to you it may be obvious, but it could used in many different ways. Your data here could be a barplot or a scatterplot; add an integer column to `DF` and it may be scatter, may be lines, it could be grouped lines. Add a numeric column instead, it could also go histogram. The reason `autoplot` methods tend to be written is that with a specific class of data, there is something "known" about it that leans very heavily to one type of plot. Without that hint, the possibilities are difficult to predict or contain.

Answer (score 0):

In R you can write your own functions easily
(and if you want to easily reuse them throughout your projects, you can go further and maintain your own packages...)

Here I throw up a low effort auto type tool; if you at least know that the dataframe is suitable for a bar chart, having a non-numeric field, and a numeric field, then this code can attempt to identify those  (first encountered are used) and throw up a plot

```
df1 <- data.frame(major = c("Bio", "Chem", "Comp", "DataSci", "Maths", "STEM_other"),
           count = c(38, 16, 19, 8, 15, 56))
library(tidyverse)


myauto <- function(data){
  ggplot(data=data) + 
    aes(x=!!sym(names(select(data,where(\(x)!is.numeric(x)))) |> head(1)),
        y=!!sym(names(select(data,where(\(x)is.numeric(x)))) |> head(1))) + geom_col()
  
}
myauto(df1)
```

Comment: I don't understand when this will be useful.

Comment: it does what the poster said they hoped autoplot would do, in the situation they were in. quote from further comments "So, follow-up question: does there exist a function that does what I described above?"